# How does builder pattern works

Tags: java, design-patterns

Ruby (Rails) programmer for 2 years, just switched to another team that uses Java.  Have some questions about Java builder pattern.

I understand the benefits of using this pattern, namely to avoid the telescoping constructor and the java bean setters which creates an inconsistent state but I have trouble understanding exactly how it works, the following is the exact pattern the team requires me to use:

```
public class Person
{
    //why is it so important that this be final, hence immutable
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;

    // Constructor
    public Person(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    //I have absolutely no idea what is this for and why is this necessary
    public static Builder builder()
    {
        return new Builder();
    }

    //This is an inner class, where person is the outer class (the owning class)
    //but why is this has to be a static class?
    public static class Builder
    {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;

        public Builder withFirstName(String firstName)
        {
            //this.firstName refers to the Builder instance firstName
            this.firstName = firstName;
            return this;
            //what is this return this?  returning this instance of the Builder object?
        }

        public Builder withLastName(String lastName)
        {
            this.lastName = lastName;
            return this;
        }

        public Person build()
        {
            return new Person(firstName, lastName);
            //firstName and lastName here refer to the Builder's object instance vars,
            //and used to create a new person object
        }
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
Person p = new Person.Builder(5).firstName("foo").lastName("bar").build();
```

1) What is the param "5" to the Builder for?

2) Why is it the Builder inner class be static?

3) What is the use of public static Builder builder() method?

4) Am I correct that we are actually creating a new inner class - Builder object, which the build method within this inner class return a new Person object?

5) It seems that to create this Person class, I would have to double the memory usage, one for the outer class and one for the inner class, is that in-efficient?

6) Am I correct that I can still create a new person object by Person p = new Person("foo", "bar");

7) How would someone unit test this?  How to unit test the setters and getters?

8) Can I perform validation on any of the fields?

9) How do I specifiy that a field is required, so it will throw an exception were someone tries to build one with only a firstName, but no lastName supplied.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you even tried reading the design pattern once? You will get your answers.

Comment: Read the [wiki article](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

Answer (score 3):

1. I don't get this one. There are no constructors defined in the `Builder` class, so that means that the compiler will automatically generate a parameterless one.
2. If the `Builder` class wasn't static, you would need an instance of your enclosing class to access the inner class. This would be a "chicken and egg" problem: the inner class is used to obtain instances of the outer class, but you first need an instance of the outer class to use it! The `static` modifier makes it so that an instance of the outer class is not needed to use it.
3. This is an example of a *factory method*. For now, it just creates an instance of `Builder` and returns it, but in the future, this could be changed to, say, create an instance and modify it before returning it, or perform a security check before returning an instance.
4. Yes, you are right. You create an instance of the inner class, and you use its `build` method to obtain an instance of its outer class.
5. Most of the time, there is a tradeoff between good design and good efficiency. But this time, although you are doubling memory usage (since both classes contain two variables of type `String`), the actual memory usage is not that much. (If you do run out of memory, you can change the JVM heap space by passing arguments to the JVM.)
6. Yes, you can, as there as a `public` constructor in the `Person` class that takes two `String` objects.
7. One can unit test this by creating an instance of `Builder`, use its `withFirstName` and `withLastName` methods to set the name, and then call the getter methods on the returned `Person` object and then check to see if they are equal to the passed-in values (using the String `equals` method).
8. You could check to see whether or not the arguments meet the preconditions by using the methods in the `String` class, and throw an exception if they are not.
9. (I'm assuming that what you mean is that if one passes in `null` for the values, which would be the case because of default initialization.) You can take advantage of a handy method introduced in the `java.util.Objects` class introduced in Java 7, `Objects.requireNonNull()`. Pass an argument to it, and it will throw an exception if the argument is `null`. Otherwise, it will return the argument.

Comment: thank you very much for the detail explanation.  It helps me a lot in understanding this pattern.

Comment: @user2712937 Like my answer? Accept it as the official answer!